# httpwebrequest over TLS fails in server

Tags: ssl, httpwebrequest

My web application is built on .Net 4.0 and am trying to connect to api over https/TLS. Connection always times out on TLS but works well when using SSL3 if I add the below line in Application_Start(),

```
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

If I enforce TLS by adding ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls, it fails. Interestingly, irrespective of the protocol (SSL/TLS) I use, I am able to get the response if I run the application using visual studio local host but fails only if executed from windows server.

I need to connect using only TLS as SSL3 will be disabled for the services. Does it have anything to do with IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If it works with SSL 3.0 but not with TLS 1.0 or higher it can be a problem on the server side or with some middleboxes (load balancer, reverse proxy etc). Mostly this is not a problem which can be fixed on the client side.